# How do I use the host's serial port with VxSim?

Tags: vxworks

Can I use the hosts serial port through VxSim in VxWorks 5.5?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: NO
Long Answer: It depends.
On Solaris, we designed the infrastructure to talk to a simulated backplane, I believe we used the host OS' pipe infrastructure.